# Looking for Windows RAM Disk which mirrors writes to hard disk

Tags: windows, ramdisk

I'm looking for a RAM disk (preferably free) which gets its contents from a specified folder on the hard disk and also writes changes made to it back to that folder. Is there such a thing for Windows?

Comment: No, it's not. That question is about ramdisks in general, and not talking anything about hard disk sync.

Comment: Isn't this what Windows disk cache does?

Comment: Should be I guess. In practice when I compile my solution on a RAM disk its twice as fast as using the hard disk, even when compiling several times in a row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with [VSuite Ramdisk](http://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/vsuite-ramdisk/index.html). Unfortunately it's **shareware** (50$).

It supports (almost) [realtime syncing](http://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/vsuite-ramdisk/support/image-file-2.html#real-time-save) to hard disk.

Fundamental problem with truly realtime sync would be huge performance loss. If syncing would be synchronous, RAM disk writing speed would be same as with hard disk. Reading speed would be faster though.

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Of course I meant asynchronously syncing the data back to hard disk. :)

Comment: Some other RAM disk software offers a backup feature too: [Dataram](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk), [SuperSpeed](http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/ramdisk.php).

Answer (score 4):

For those looking for a free alternative, you can achieve something similar by creating a RAM disk through [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/) and then following the steps I outlined here: [Keeping HDD files in virtual memory without changing paths to files](https://superuser.com/questions/699662/keeping-hdd-files-in-virtual-memory-without-changing-paths-to-files#701768).

> Assuming that:
>
> - you already created a RAM drive in physical memory assigned to `R:` (any other letter is fine too).
> - you want to make the folder `C:\Folder1` available in RAM for faster access.
> - `Folder1` is stored on a local NTFS formatted volume.
>
> ### Applying the changes
>
> 1. Close all programs that might be accessing `Folder1`.
> 2. Rename `Folder1` to `Folder1.zTarget` (the actual name is not important as long as it's different).
> 3. Copy `Folder1.zTarget` to RAM drive (`R:`).
> 4. Create a [directory junction link][1] named `Folder1` pointing to `R:\Folder1.zTarget`.
>
> From now on, every time you access `C:\Folder1` what you're actually
>   accessing is the data stored on the RAM drive (`R:\Folder1.zTarget`).
>
> ### Reverting back
>
> 1. Close all programs that might be accessing `Folder1` (now a directory junction link).
> 2. If any file inside `Folder1` was modified, copy the `Folder1.zTarget` from RAM (`R:`) to disk (`C:`) to preserve the
>      changes.
> 3. Delete the directory junction link named `Folder1`.
> 4. Rename `Folder1.zTarget` back to `Folder1`.

Check the linked answer for a working batch script example.

Syncing would be on-demand only, which is the best option performance-wise. Eventually one could get automatic sync by writing data back to disk every, say, 15 minutes (e.g. through a scheduled task).