# Create temporary disk in RAM?

Tags: windows, ramdisk

The Fossil SCM currently doesn't support grepping through the repository. The only way to find code, is to check out the whole repository into a disk through "fossil deconstruct c:\temp_fossil", and grep through the files.

To avoid writing the files to disk and improve performance, I was thinking of creating a temporary disk in RAM.

Does someone know of a way to do this in Windows (XPSP3)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [DataRAM RAMDisk](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk) for a few years. I use it for scratch/temp space, but one of its features is that it saves the content to a disk image when you reboot, so it is persistent.

Just remember that any RAM you allocate to a RAMDisk will no longer be available to other applications, so if you make it too large you'll hurt system performance. I've set up a 1GB RAMDisk, but have 8GB on Win7-64 so I've got enough to spare.

There are also a few [related](https://superuser.com/questions/248419/looking-for-windows-ram-disk-which-mirrors-writes-to-hard-disk?rq=1) SU post linked on the right here.