# Keeping HDD files in virtual memory without changing paths to files

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, 64-bit, ramdisk

I suppose my question is very specific, but I hope there might be solution already.

I want to make few folders available in virtual memory but not changing the way they are accessed like virtualization tool that will copy files in virtual memory and redirects IO operation to those files to virtual memory.

I have huge source folders that are often recompiled by maven, and I want to increase overall build speed by making those sources available in ram instead of hdd.

I'm familiar with ImDisk but I cant break environment by changing paths to sources (there are lot of tools already configured).

So the question is : is there any solution for above described problem?

Regards

Comment: You are using the wrong term. Virtual memory is the process that allows memory address to be either mapped to physical RAM or to be redirected to a pagefile on a hard drive. What you are looking for is some kind of transparent [Ram Disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain sorry I used wrong term, I really mean phisical RAM. Is it possible anyway? I mean can one write such a tool that would have permission to redirect IO operations? (I'm not sure if system does provide such permission at all)

Comment: I know software like [sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) does IO redirection, but I don't know if it will give you that performance boost you are looking for or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Possible solution

Assuming that:

- you already created a RAM drive in physical memory assigned to `R:` (any other letter is fine too).
- you want to make the folder `C:\Folder1` available in RAM for faster access.
- `Folder1` is stored on a local NTFS formatted volume.

### Applying the changes

1. Close all programs that might be accessing `Folder1`.
2. Rename `Folder1` to `Folder1.zTarget` (the actual name is not important as long as it's different).
3. Copy `Folder1.zTarget` to RAM drive (`R:`).
4. Create a [directory junction link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) named `Folder1` pointing to `R:\Folder1.zTarget`.

From now on, every time you access `C:\Folder1` what you're actually accessing is the data stored on the RAM drive (`R:\Folder1.zTarget`).

### Reverting back

1. Close all programs that might be accessing `Folder1` (now a directory junction link).
2. If any file inside `Folder1` was modified, copy the `Folder1.zTarget` from RAM (`R:`) to disk (`C:`) to preserve the changes.
3. Delete the directory junction link named `Folder1`.
4. Rename `Folder1.zTarget` back to `Folder1`.

## Batch automation

Even though most of the steps can be performed manually, there's no built-in way to create directory junctions links but from the command line interface (`mklink`). While we're at it, we can save time by automating the whole process.

### Example script

After a brief initialization, the script will check if there are any folders whose name contains the custom suffix. It will then proceed either applying or reverting the changes for each folder set in the `folders` variable, just as described above - except for the "close all programs" steps.

```
@echo off
set folders="C:\Folder1","C:\Some other\folder"
set suffix=zTarget
set ramdisk=R:

for %%G in (%folders%) do (
dir "%%~dpG" /a:d | find ".%suffix%" >nul
goto :check
)

:check
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" goto :revert

:apply
for %%G in (%folders%) do (
if exist "%%~G\" (
ren "%%~G" "%%~nG.%suffix%"
xcopy "%%~G.%suffix%" "%ramdisk%%%~pnG.%suffix%" /e /i /f /h /r /k /y /j
mklink /j "%%~G" "%ramdisk%%%~pnG.%suffix%"
echo.
))
goto :end

:revert
for %%G in (%folders%) do (
if exist "%%~G.%suffix%\" (
xcopy "%ramdisk%%%~pnG.%suffix%" "%%~G.%suffix%" /e /i /f /h /r /k /y /j 
rd "%%~G"
ren "%%~G.%suffix%" "%%~nG"
echo.
))

:end
pause
exit /b
```

Comment: Could you please suggest good resource to learn batch scripting like this?

Comment: Here are a few links that should get you started: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php http://ss64.com/nt/commands.html http://www.dostips.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, for those who might be interested in results, my projects build in 2min instead of 16...

Comment: What are your tech specs?

Comment: Win7 : intel xeon e5-1620 3.60GHz, 16GB Ram, my projects are really heavy, lot of maven projects nested, and total sources that are getting compiled every time are over 1GB... My CPU was not higher 10%  while maven build, but now I can see its working properly... (not using parallel build)